# CreateIfnotExists throws a connection error

Tags: azure, iis, azure-storage

CreateIfNotExists method throws an error:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 52.140.168.120:443

when an Application pool identity is used.

```
// Parse the connection string and return a reference to the storage account.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

            if (container.CreateIfNotExists())
            {
                BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions() { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob };
                container.SetPermissions(containerPermissions);
                container.CreateIfNotExists();
            }
```

But this works on using the custom user account and password. 
Is there a way to get this working using the Application Pool Identity.

Comment: It would probably help if you edited your question to show actual code.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have added the code now

Comment: I don't really see how the user context executing the code could affect the result. Azure Storage only looks at the connection string anyway?

Comment: It looks like you've proved that the issue is in the application pool. How is this pool configured? For example, if you have restrictions on .NET version then HTTPS might not support the features required by Azure Storage.

Comment: @MichaelRoberson-MSFT I'm using .net 4.6.1 and storage account is using https

Comment: As an experiment, could you try using http? Also do check the configuration of the application pool.